# Farelogix SOAP connection with PHP

Tags: soap

I am new to SOAP. Can anyone tell me how to access the Farelogix Third-Party XML API Developer Sandbox when credentials are provided ?

Comment: Do you want to write code to do this in any particular language?  Really SOAP just describes the API's type/transport.  Or are you looking more to browse the data returned?

Comment: @ficuscr: FAQs for PHP support says client must formulate their own SOAP wrapper. I would like to write my request and browse the response. I do have sample WSDLs and API schemas. But I am stuck with how to kickstart with the given samples and credentials for SOAP request.

Comment: What have you tried?  Your question is too broad to answer.  Do they have any code examples in their portal you can use?  Also authentication with SOAP can be done a number of ways.  Look at the WSDL where the auth part is, start googling around "php soap request  authentication headers".  When you get more specific problems and can't find answers ask again here.  (and maybe add PHP tag to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this for how to use SOAP in php:
[Send XML with php via post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796173/send-xml-with-php-via-post#answer-17796669)

Here is example how to use client credentials:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#88902